# Pillow image no transparency

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Ive looked around finding numerous answers and none seem to work.
I'm able to get a picture in my Tkinter window using pillow, it is a white circle on a transparent background. The image is a png and i've used `Image.mode` to discover that it is the correct type (RGBA) to my knowledge.

All that appears in its place is a white square the same size as the image.

I am using python3 and should mention I removed PIL using pip and installed Pillow.

The circle i am trying to use is https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yevuc.png

My code looks like this

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win = Tk()

win.title("Transparency")
win.config(bg='#636363')

load = Image.open("on.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="on.png")

img = Label(win, image=render)
img.image = render

img.place(x=0, y=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Everything works fine apart from the image being transparent.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Im on a MacBook Air running macOS Catalina

Answer (score 1):

Transparency is working, it's just that you're having difficulty seeing the effect it has because you haven't specified a background color for the `Label` widget (and the default is probably grey).

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win = Tk()

win.title("Transparency")
win.config(bg='#636363')

load = Image.open("on.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="on.png")

img = Label(win, image=render, bg='red')  # Added background.
img.image = render

img.place(x=0, y=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of result:

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems like there is a different issue, the background of the label changed however the image is simply not showing now. It's just a red square with the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Perhaps the different results are due to other things. I'm using Python 3.8.0 and PIL/Pillow 6.2.1. on Winows 7.

Comment: I suspect this issue you're having is because Apple is stopping (or has stopped) the shipping of script languages like Python starting in MaxOS Catalina. See this [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361840/when-updating-to-macos-catalina-will-the-default-python-installation-get-removed) on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I copied the script over to my Windows laptop and it works perfectly, definitely a Mac issue. Thank you for your contribution and help @martineau